# Displaying sub-category of a category in Django

Tags: python, django

I want to list my products like this

- Category

  - Sub-Category

    - Product1

Models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    PRODUCTS_CATEGORY = [
        ('None', 'None'),
        ('Category1', 'Category1'),
        ('Category2', 'Category2'),
        ('Category3', 'Category3'),
        ('Category4', 'Category4'),
        ('Category5', 'Category5'),
        ('Category6', 'Category6')
    ]
    PRODUCTS_SUB_CATEGORY = [
        ('NA', 'NA'),
        ('Sub-Category1', 'Sub-Category1'),
        ('Sub-Category2', 'Sub-Category2'),
        ('Sub-Category3', 'Sub-Category3'),
        ('Sub-Category4', 'Sub-Category4'),
        ('Sub-Category5', 'Sub-Category5')
    ]
    prod_id = models.AutoField
    prod_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    prod_category = models.CharField(
        max_length=100, choices=PRODUCTS_CATEGORY, default='None')
    prod_sub_category = models.CharField(
        max_length=100, choices=PRODUCTS_SUB_CATEGORY, default='NA')
    prod_desc = models.TextField()
    prod_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='product_images')
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.prod_name
```

The current views.py is used to display the products in the following way

- Category1

  - Product

I want additional code that gives me a different view(below) along with the above view in the same views.py function

- Category

  - Sub-Category

    - Product1

views.py

```
def product(request):
    allProds = []
    catprods = Product.objects.values('prod_category', 'id')
    cats = {item['prod_category'] for item in catprods}
    for cat in cats:
        prod = Product.objects.filter(prod_category=cat)
        n = len(prod)
        nSlides = n // 4 + ceil((n / 4) - (n // 4))
        allProds.append([prod, range(1, nSlides), nSlides])

    params = {'allProds': allProds, 'ster_prods': ster_prods}
    return render(request, 'website/products.html', params)
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried and describe specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to do, it may be easier to make Category and SubCategory tables in your database instead of tuples, then assign each product to a subcategory and subcategory to a category, like so:

```
class Category(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class SubCategory(models.Model):
       parent_category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING) #you can also make this a many-to-many if you want
       name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    
class Product(models.Model):
        prod_id = models.AutoField
        prod_name = models.CharField(max_length=100) 
        prod_sub_category = models.ForeignKey(SubCategory, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)#again, here you can also do a many-to-many relationship
        prod_desc = models.TextField()
        prod_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='product_images')
        slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.prod_name
```

Now, in the view, you can query a category or subcategory and pull all products associated with it easier.

Comment: can you help me do it without having to create a new database and just use a tuple instead?

Comment: Without creating new tables the queries become more complex and the use of a sub-category becomes pretty useless.